# How to fetch text (stream encoded with filter FlateDecode) in annotations using pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, annotations, pdf.js

Need to solve with pdf.js:

a) Using pdf.js It's possible get annotations with getAnnotations() but not any information regarding the text within that annotation. How to extract  it?

b) How to fetch a stream from an object (ref: gen num) like:

```
/N: 8 0 R
/Filter:FlateDecode
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got answers to my doubts using:

- [pdf.js.utils](https://github.com/brendandahl/pdf.js.utils) (browser) from brendandahl (GitHub)
- [PDF Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) and Adobe Extensions to the PDF Specification

I'll explain the problem and solution.

**Problem**

Extract text from annotations in PDFs using PDF.js display layer.

**Solution**

PDF.js has different layers:

1. *Core*: layer where a binary PDF is parsed
2. *Display*: using core layer render PDFs an get information of a document
3. *Viewer*: UI for PDF viewer in Firefox and other browser extension

For extracting text from annotation it's necessary work in *Core* and *Display* layer.

*I. Core layer*:

> Create a public property (annotationText) with all the texts in annotation

a) Modify src/core/annotation.js

a.1) *class Annotation* constructor: add a line and the end of the constructor

```
    // Expose public properties using a data object.
    this.data = {
      ... 
      annotationText: this._extractText(params) // -> Add this line *****
    };

  }
```

a.2) *class Annotation* - add method for extract text:

```
      _extractText(params) {
      // AP - Appearance Dictionary
      let appearanceDictionary = params.dict.get('AP');
      // No AP
      if (typeof appearanceDictionary === 'undefined') {
         return '';
      }

      // N - Stream 
      let normalAppearance = appearanceDictionary.xref.fetch(appearanceDictionary._map.N);
      normalAppearance.getBytes()
      // No text
      if (typeof normalAppearance.buffer === 'undefined') {
         return '';
      }

      let numParentheses = 0;
      let streamText = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < normalAppearance.buffer.length; i++) {
        if (String.fromCharCode(normalAppearance.buffer[i]) === ")") {
          numParentheses--;
        }
        if (numParentheses > 0) {
        streamText += String.fromCharCode(normalAppearance.buffer[i]);
        }
        if (String.fromCharCode(normalAppearance.buffer[i]) === "(") {
          numParentheses++;
        }
      }

      return streamText;
    }
```

b) Bundle all *src/* files into two production scripts (*pdf.js* and *pdf.worker.js*)

```
 $ gulp generic
```

*II. Display layer*:

> Display texts in *annotationText*

```
  page.getAnnotations().then(
    function (annotations) {

      let textInAnnotations = ""
      for (annotation in annotations) {

         textInAnnotations = textInAnnotations + " - " + annotations[annotation].annotationText

      }

      console.log("Text in annotations: "+textInAnnotations)

    });
```